# Angular ui-bootsrap tabs no content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Trying to use tabs from `angular-ui`.

My template:

```
<div id="footer" ng-controller="LoggerController">

        <button id="logger_button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" class="btn">
        </button>

        <div id="log_div" collapse="isCollapsed">
            <div class="log_tab_div" style="height: 240px; width: 100%;">
                 <tabset>
                    <tab heading="Static title">Some sontent</tab>
                    <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
                </tabset>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I see tabs, but there is no content in this tabs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please post the `LoggerController` code?

Your footer `div` isn't closed.

Have you added the angular-ui bootstrap script `http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js` to your page and injected `ui.bootstrap` into you angular app module as follows `angular.module('aModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);`?

If all those conditions are met then you should be fine, I think. :)